# “make all” error while compiling TPlink wm722n driver

Tags: compiler-errors, linux-kernel, driver

I have downloaded the Tplink wm722n V2 driver from the tplink website. when i tried to 'make' it give me a error...

```
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-686-pae/build M=/root/Desktop/kernel-master/drivers/TL-WN722N_v2.0-Ralink/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417-target-kernel_4.4  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.9.0-kali3-686-pae/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1367: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Can anyone help me out please..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kali live usb "Module w0 not found in directory" Broadcom 4360](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324082/kali-live-usb-module-w0-not-found-in-directory-broadcom-4360)

Comment: and/or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332404/install-amd-drivers-on-kali-2-0

Answer (score 2):

the error says that make is looking for the kernel headers but it can't find them on the path specified.

you need to install `linux-headers` then you can build a module.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade your system first , because the `4.9.0` kernel version is no longer on kali linux repository , then install the appropriate kernel headers package.

```
apt update ; apt upgrade ; apt dist-upgrade
reboot
```

Then install the `linux-headers` pacakge:

```
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Also you can use `apt-cache search linux-image` to find the available package then specify the package version to be installed.

The latest available `linux-image` [can be found here](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/linux):

```
apt install linux-image-4.14.0-kali1-686-pae
apt install linux-headers-4.14.0-kali1-686-pae
reboot
```